# Can you populate a set with soql?

Tags: apex-code, soql

Can you populate a set from a soql query?  I couldn't get my syntax to work

Set  c = [select id From Contact limit 1000 ];

thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to declare the type of your set and make use of the set constructor that takes a list as a parameter giving you something like this:

```
Set<Contact> c = new Set<Contact>( [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact LIMIT 1000] );
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know the set constructor!

Comment: Any way to get a `Set<String>` directly from SOQL?

Comment: ^^ Ditto, or even a `Set<Date>` directly from SOQL?